# Running .asm file via SSH

Tags: assembly, ssh, fedora, mars-simulator

I would like to run .asm file having MARS 4.5 installed on Fedora distribution, but remotely, via SSH connction.
What should be the command for that? If there exists.

Comment: `ssh user@host 'the command you want to run'` (note: an assembly source file, e.g. `.asm`, is not independently executable until it is compiled into an executable)

Comment: If MARS only has a GUI mode then you want to do X forwarding and have a local X server.

Comment: @Jester: MARS can be run from the command line with `java -jar mars.jar [options] program.asm [more files...] [ pa arg1 [more args...]]`  ([docs](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/MarsHelpCommand.html)).  But if you're *developing* asm you almost certainly want the GUI for its debugger.  The text console debugger isn't as nice.